# Stop bootstrap modal from closing when outside the window is clicked?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In jqModal it's possible to specify that the window should remain open unless directly closed by a button or via javascript. That is, when the overlay is clicked the modal window does not close.

I can't find a way to do this in bootstrap - is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap v3 then the following will work:

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

EDIT: in fact, this will work with older versions of bootstrap too (I just checked 2.3.2 and it works there too)

EDIT 2: The attribute needs to be placed on your modal div